# Погрешность запуска cron задач

Tags: cron

На руткоде не дали ответа, поэтому сюда.

Стоит задача на cron выполнение раз в час. Утром задача выполнялась ровно по direct-time.ru Сейчас выполняется на несколько секунд раньше.

Тп хостинга ответили:

> Здравствуйте, в работе cron
> допускается погрешность в несколько
> секунд.

Мне важно, что бы задача выполнялась не секундой раньше не позже исходя из времени direct-time.ru

Как мне быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ставить выполнение за 10(пример) секунд раньше, и за t(10) сек сверятся с direct-time.ru,и ждать наступления времени X, по наступлении которого выполнять задачу.

Comment: @ToRcH565, не совсем понял, что Вы написали :o

>> и за t(10) сек сверятся с direct-time.ru
особенно это.

Comment: объясните поподробнее на счёт 

> и за t(10) сек сверятся с direct-time.ru,и ждать наступления времени X

Comment: T- выбраное вами время старта скрипта в скобках указано что выбрано для примера, т.е. запускаете скрипт за 10 сек до нужного времени, и ждете пока наступит нужное вам время запуска, и только тогда начинаете выполнять действия, а в течении этих 10 сек проводите проверку точности начального запуска вашего скрипта кроном, и корректируете время ожидания до запуска действий... 10 сек просто для наглядности выбрано.